# Should data for table filter be filtered in backend or frontend?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, pagination

For a table that has pagination and a filter that contains the distinct value of the column, should the data be paginated and filtered at backend or frontend?

Initially, I wanted to filter the data at backend with pagination where we filter with pageNo, pageSize. But after adding a distinct value filter, I am faced with two issues, first is that frontend will require the distinct value for each column, and second is that the repository layer will require to allow having a filter for all the columns.

Filtering on frontend however will require getting the entire dataset, which could go to millions of records.

The API is using springboot querying on mariaDB.

Example of the table:

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to go through millions of records, then definitely backend. The data takes long time to travel in internet, you know.